# What do the keys in the '_performanceLogger' object of an XMLHttpRequest response mean?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, performance, axios, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to measure download (and later upload) speed using Axios in React Native. My question's relate to the most appropriate way to do so, and understanding if the `_performanceLogger` in the response from XMLHttpRequest is accurate for this purpose. There surprisingly doesn't seem to be much out there about `_performanceLogger` ... Appreciate the help!

A MWE is:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

// Dummy API endpoint
let requestURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2'

// Getting timestamp immediately before request is started
var startTimestamp = (new Date()).getTime()

// Make request through Axios
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get(requestURL)
.then(function (response) {
    // Handle success
    console.log("And I am burdened with glorious purpose.")
    
    // Getting timestamp immediately after request is completed
    let endTimestamp = (new Date()).getTime()
    console.log("Request start time stamp: " + startTimestamp)
    console.log("Request completed time stamp: " + endTimestamp)
    
    // Logging the whole _performanceLogger object
    let responsePerformanceLogger = response.request._performanceLogger
    console.log('Perf Logger:')
    console.log(responsePerformanceLogger)
    
    // Logging the key/value specific to the actual request within the _performanceLogger object
    let requestPerfString = 'network_XMLHttpRequest_' + requestURL
    let responseTimespans = responsePerformanceLogger._timespans[requestPerfString]
    console.log('Specific Request Timings:')
    console.log(responseTimespans)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle error
    console.log("This is a mistake! I shouldn't be here!")
    console.log(error);
    
})
.then(function () {
    // always executed
    console.log('For all time! Always!')
});
```

I use Expo to run this code on my device, and I get the following output to the console:

```
And I am burdened with glorious purpose.
Request start time stamp: 1640229022039
Request completed time stamp: 1640229022156
Perf Logger:
PerformanceLogger {
  "_closed": false,
  "_extras": Object {},
  "_pointExtras": Object {},
  "_points": Object {
    "initializeCore_end": 194691080.25150004,
    "initializeCore_start": 194691027.19495836,
  },
  "_timespans": Object {
    "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://192.168.1.40:19000/logs": Object {
      "endExtras": undefined,
      "endTime": 194692352.89145836,
      "startExtras": undefined,
      "startTime": 194691383.22187504,
      "totalTime": 969.6695833206177,
    },
    "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://192.168.1.40:19001/symbolicate": Object {
      "endExtras": undefined,
      "endTime": 194694267.96945837,
      "startExtras": undefined,
      "startTime": 194694100.6875417,
      "totalTime": 167.2819166779518,
    },
    "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2": Object {
      "endExtras": undefined,
      "endTime": 194699846.2774167,
      "startExtras": undefined,
      "startTime": 194699738.0606667,
      "totalTime": 108.21674999594688,
    },
  },
}
Specific Request Timings:
Object {
  "endExtras": undefined,
  "endTime": 194699846.2774167,
  "startExtras": undefined,
  "startTime": 194699738.0606667,
  "totalTime": 108.21674999594688,
}
For all time! Always!
```

**My specific questions are:**

1. What are the different objects under the `_timespans` key? There are two (log, symbolicate) to the local IP for Expo ... what's happening here? Presumably these won't  there when I deploy outside of Expo.
2. Is the third, the one that contains the actual URL made in the request, the actual timing of the download? (I've extracted this one as `Specific Request Timings`.) This is total download time (latency + file download), correct?
3. Is relying on the XMLHttpRequest timing less/more accurate than just using the simple `getTime()` timestamps that I have called before the request and after successful completion? I would expect that they should be close, but the `getTime()`'s require some finite execution time that could be variable by device/load.